# What's these Realm model in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm begginger to learn realm.
 
I try to practice using realm.
And I use realm browser to open default.realm.
What's these model is like _Class, _Permission, _Realm, _Role, _User.......?
But I don't set them.
I just set "Item" and "Type".
Is this normal to use realm?
Who can help me to fix it?
because it makes my db looks ugly.
Thanks, All.

[image: hello, This is question.]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let items = realm.objects(Item.self)

    if items.count > 0 { return }

    let type1 = Type()
    type1.name = "Shopping"
    let type2 = Type()
    type2.name = "Fun"


    let item1 = Item(value: ["computer", 1000, Date(), type1])

    let item2 = Item()
    item2.name = "movie"
    item2.cost = 50.00
    item2.date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -36000)
    item2.type = type2

    let item3 = Item()
    item3.name = "beef"
    item3.cost = 2.00
    item3.date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -72000)
    item3.type = type1

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(item1)
        realm.add(item2)
        realm.add(item3)
    }

    print(realm.configuration.fileURL ?? "")
}

}
```

Comment: I believe this is a system tables. They have to do with user management and permissions.

Comment: If they look ugly to you, then just ignore them :). They won't be available to your code anyway.

Comment: ok, I got it. Thanks.